# PHP search video files in directory and display single video

Tags: php, video

I am Justin and new to Stackoverflow. We have a yearly familyweekend and every year someone else creates the entertainment. This year it is my turn. I am creating a game (treasure hunt) with the use of an iPad.

For this I am looking for a script that can search for a filename in a directory and when found, display the file (video) in the page. I am a little familiar with PHP, but not very.

It does not require any database it can be very simple because it will only contain a few videos. But I can't find any scripts that quite do what I need. Every script is either to complicated and advanced or does not show the video but the filestring.

Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction? Thanks so  much in advance.

Regards, 
Justin

Comment: Please add code which you tried

Comment: If by "filestring" you mean the path to the video that's all you need, after you have that info use HTML to render your video by inserting the string in a [video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would be possible if I were that familiar with PHP coding. Is there anyway you can show me an example on how to do this? Because I don't want to show the path, I want it to directly open the video that has been found.

Answer (score 0):

to check if a specific file exists in a directory you can use `file_exists()` method.
Please check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would be possible if I were that familiar with PHP coding. Is there anyway you can show me an example on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry new to Stackofverflow, this was not for your comment, but the one above.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying and trying, I think I found the answer. Below the script for anyone looking for this.

```
<?php
$dir = 'directoryname'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['formname']))? strtolower($_GET['formname']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
    if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
        echo "<video width='320' height='240' controls>";
        echo "<source src='$dir/$file'>$file type='video/mp4'>";
        echo "</video>";    
        echo ""; 
        echo "<br>"; 
    } 
} 
closedir($res); 
?>
```

And the form

```
<form action="search.php" method="get"><input name="formname"
type="text"> <input type="submit"></form>
```